# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I've been trying to connect kafka to elasticsearch using kafka-connect api.Kafka version is 0.11.0.0.These are the steps I followed:

1.Buiding Elasticsearch Connector:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch.git

2.Build the connector

```
$ cd kafka-connect-elasticsearch
$ mvn clean package
```

3.Finally running the script:

```
$ bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/elasticsearch-connect.properties
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:221)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:68)
```

Can't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Maybe just try and install the Confluent Open Source distribution that includes a 0.11 and the Elasticsearch Connector and follow the QuickStart here http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html

Comment: I've done the whole code without using Confluent and switching over it now is not what I'm planning.Isn't there a solution to this ?

Comment: It's just a suggestion to help you determine if the problem is your setup, your build environment, or the Confluent ES Connector itself.

Comment: 0.11 added CLASSPATH isolation so perhaps you don't have all the required dependencies listed in plugin.path. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-146+-+Classloading+Isolation+in+Connect

Answer (score 7):

From experience, this error means that you are bringing an older version of `guava` earlier in your classpath. Connect worker requires `guava >= 20` for `org.reflections` to work correctly.

`kafka-connect-elasticsearch` or any other connector that brings with it `guava 18.0` or older will prohibit the worker from starting up. This error message means that the older `guava` jar was encountered first in the classpath.

Two solutions:

1. Indeed, as [Hans Jespersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4950528/hans-jespersen) mentions, using classloading isolation by setting your `plugin.path` in Connect worker's configuration, will allow the connector to work *as-is* without interfering with the Connect framework.
2. If adding the connector to the CLASSPATH is your only option, make sure it's added after Kafka Connect's dependencies, so that the most recent `guava` will be picked up.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to describe the answer for your problem https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/issues/104

> It's a little confusing, but after you build the connector there are a
>   number of things in the target directory. The
>   kafka-connect-elasticsearch-.jar is only the JAR file with
>   the connector code, but that doesn't include all the libraries. One of
>   those directories in the target directory, namely
>   target/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-*-development/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/,
>   does contain all the libraries. Add this directory to the Kafka
>   Connect worker's classpath, or copy all of those JAR files into a
>   directory that is already on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, I have a similar issue w/ no usage for kafka. I spent a lot of hours to try to figure out the issue, and finally, I have a pattern.

In my project, I used [ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-extensions:1.8.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ro.isdc.wro4j/wro4j-extensions/1.8.0), and [org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.11)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The conflict happened becuase [ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-extensions:1.8.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ro.isdc.wro4j/wro4j-extensions/1.8.0) used [com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20160315](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.javascript/closure-compiler/v20160315), I solved it by exclude [com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:v20160315](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.javascript/closure-compiler/v20160315) from the pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>closure-compiler</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

However, the problem is a build-dependent which we don't know which jar may cause the conflict. In this case, you need to know the location of the jar by running something like the following:

```
CodeSource source = com.google.common.collect.Sets.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if(source != null)
    logger.warn(source.getLocation().toString());
```

and see what is the output. In my case, the output is

```
file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8087-ROOT.war-_-any-1541284168668078443.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/closure-compiler-v20160315.jar
```

Hopefully, the answer will help you to find a way to solve the issue,

Mughrabi

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error recently (Jan 2020) on my localhost (macOS Catalina) and was able to resolve this by updating my `.zprofile` file (zsh shell). If you have bash shell, you can make changes to `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file.

• Error was caused because my jvm.classpath was including dependencies of `guava` verison < 20. My `.zprofile` file had exports to `hadoop-3.1.1` and `apache-hive-3.1.1` which was the issue for error.

• I am using `kafka_2.12-2.0.0`. So, I just commented the `hadoop-3.1.1` & `apache-hive-3.1.1`in my `.zprofile` and ran my twitter kafka connector successfully.

• I was able to trace this error by following the comments in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842850/kafka-connect-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-collect-setssetvie/48850184#48850184) by @Konstantine Karantasis.

Hope this is helpful.