# Kafka Connect java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup kafka-connect-cassandra on an AWS instance.

I have setup `plugin.path` in `connect-avro-distributed.properties` file:

```
plugin.path=/home/ubuntu/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/plugins
```

And I have `kafka-connect-cassandra-1.0.0-1.0.0-all.jar` in:

```
/home/ubuntu/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/plugins/lib
```

This is the traceback:

```
[2018-02-18 10:28:33,268] INFO Kafka Connect distributed worker initializing ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:60)
[2018-02-18 10:28:33,278] INFO WorkerInfo values: 
    jvm.args = -Xmx256M, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35, -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Dkafka.logs.dir=/var/log/kafka, -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties
    jvm.spec = Oracle Corporation, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_151, 25.151-b12
    jvm.classpath = /home/ubuntu/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/plugins:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/paranamer-2.7.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-servlets-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-clients-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/xz-1.5.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-security-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/connect-json-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/connect-runtime-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/connect-transforms-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/scala-library-2.11.11.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/maven-artifact-3.5.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-test-sources.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-connect-cassandra-1.0.0-1.0.0-all.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/connect-api-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-sources.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/support-metrics-client-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-scaladoc.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/support-metrics-common-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-io-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-log4j-appender-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/avro-1.8.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/lz4-java-1.4.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-client-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/snappy-java-1.1.4.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-http-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-examples-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/connect-file-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka-tools-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-continuation-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/httpmime-4.5.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-javadoc.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-test.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/common-metrics-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/build-tools-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/common-utils-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/common-config-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/java/confluent-common/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/kafka-json-serializer-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/paranamer-2.7.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/xz-1.5.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/kafka-connect-avro-converter-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/avro-1.8.2.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/kafka-schema-registry-client-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/kafka-avro-serializer-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:/usr/share/java/kafka-serde-tools/snappy-java-1.1.1.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/paranamer-2.7.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-servlets-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-clients-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/xz-1.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-security-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-json-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-runtime-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-transforms-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/scala-library-2.11.11.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/maven-artifact-3.5.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-test-sources.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-connect-cassandra-1.0.0-1.0.0-all.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-api-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-sources.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/support-metrics-client-4.0.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-scaladoc.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/support-metrics-common-4.0.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-io-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-log4j-appender-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/avro-1.8.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/guava-20.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/lz4-java-1.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-client-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/snappy-java-1.1.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-http-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-streams-examples-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/connect-file-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka-tools-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-continuation-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/httpmime-4.5.2.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-javadoc.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1-test.jar:/usr/bin/../share/java/confluent-support-metrics/*:/usr/share/java/confluent-support-metrics/*
    os.spec = Linux, amd64, 4.4.0-1049-aws
    os.vcpus = 2
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo:71)
[2018-02-18 10:28:33,279] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:69)
[2018-02-18 10:28:33,290] INFO Loading plugin from: /home/ubuntu/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/plugins/lib (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:179)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:153)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:70)
```

The first entry in `jvm.classpath` is the location where I have `kafka-connect-cassandra.jar`, inside `plugin/lib`.

**guava.jars:**

These are the paths of guava jars. Where should I place the kafka-connect-cassandra.jar or should I just remove any of these jars?

```
/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/guava-18.0.jar
/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-storage-common/guava-14.0.1.jar
/usr/share/java/kafka/guava-20.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.1/lib/guava-18.0.jar
```

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Connect framework currently carries `guava-20.0.jar` in order to use Reflections and be able to scan your `plugin.path` for Connect plugins.

Connect framework's dependencies are added to your CLASSPATH if you are starting Connect using one of its bin scripts: `connect-distributed` or `connect-standalone`.

However, somehow an older version of guava is residing first in your CLASSPATH (maybe because you've set the CLASSPATH to include such a dependency), and then Connect is unable to scan your `plugin.path` with a guava version `< 20`. That's what your exception indicates. That Connect can't scan the `plugin.path` with the version of guava it finds in your CLASSPATH.

Your `plugin.path` should contain your plugins, each on its own directory. For example, similarly to what you have above:

`plugin.path=/home/ubuntu/connect` with

`/home/ubuntu/connect/kafka_2.11-1.0.0/` and

`/home/ubuntu/connect/kafka-connect-cassandra-1.0.0-1.0.0-all.jar`

The layout above is used to make the point that plugins should not contain other plugins according to your example, but it's not recommended to set your `plugin.path` to a user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I `echo $CLASSPATH`, I am not seeing anything. Can you kindly tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Connect prints the actual classpath during startup (`jvm.classpath`) in the logs. Can you check that there's only `guava-20.0.jar` early in this variable and not any other guava, or an uber jar that might contain guava?

Comment: `jvm.classpath` contains multiple paths. I will edit the question to include the complete trace. Kindly give it a look.

Comment: And I have four `guava.jars` in the `jvm.classpath`. The first one `/usr/share/java/kafka/guava-20.0.jar`, second one `/usr/share/java/kafka/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar`, third one `/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/guava-20.0.jar` and fourth one `/usr/bin/../share/java/kafka/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar`

Comment: The problem is that the cassandra connector uber jar has guava in it probably. Take it out of that directory, set your plugin.path to something that will have cassandra uber jar and Kafka connect, but not the one inside the other.

Comment: Kindly review the updates in the question. I didn't understand `Take it out of that directory, set your plugin.path to something that will have cassandra uber jar and Kafka connect, but not the one inside the other.` this part of your comment. Can you kindly elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classpath issue. Looks like maybe you have an incompatible version of guava in the classpath? If your plugin path isn't including this method in any of the jars it has, that's a connector packaging issue. If it is, then you probably have two versions hanging around. Double check that plugin path with a find command to inspect all jars for that class in the message as a first step. Ultimately, you'll need to figure out what version of the dependency the connector expects and get that version and only that version into the plugin path.